# Problem with hadoop start-dfs.sh

Tags: server, ssh, hadoop, hyper-v

I installed and configured hadoop on my Ubuntu 14.04 server, virtualized inside of hyper-v, however I am getting an issue when i run `start-dfs.sh`

```
root@sUbuntu01:/var/log# start-dfs.sh
14/06/04 15:27:08 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
localhost]
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
-c: Unknown cipher type 'cd'
localhost: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-sUbuntu01.out
noexecstack'.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname noexecstack'.: Name or service not known
'-z: ssh: Could not resolve hostname '-z: Name or service not known
'execstack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 'execstack: Name or service not known
disabled: ssh: Could not resolve hostname disabled: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname vm: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
guard: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname vm: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
to: ssh: Could not resolve hostname to: Name or service not known
warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known
it: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it: Name or service not known
now.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname now.: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
will: ssh: Could not resolve hostname will: Name or service not known
link: ssh: Could not resolve hostname link: Name or service not known
or: ssh: Could not resolve hostname or: Name or service not known
It's: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it's: Name or service not known
<libfile>',: ssh: Could not resolve hostname <libfile>',: Name or service not known
which: ssh: connect to host which port 22: Connection timed out
have: ssh: connect to host have port 22: Connection timed out
you: ssh: connect to host you port 22: Connection timed out
try: ssh: connect to host try port 22: Connection timed out
the: ssh: connect to host the port 22: Connection timed out
highly: ssh: connect to host highly port 22: Connection timed out
might: ssh: connect to host might port 22: Connection timed out
loaded: ssh: connect to host loaded port 22: Connection timed out
You: ssh: connect to host you port 22: Connection timed out
guard.: ssh: connect to host guard. port 22: Connection timed out
library: ssh: connect to host library port 22: Connection timed out
Server: ssh: connect to host server port 22: Connection timed out
fix: ssh: connect to host fix port 22: Connection timed out
The: ssh: connect to host the port 22: Connection timed out
recommended: ssh: connect to host recommended port 22: Connection timed out
that: ssh: connect to host that port 22: Connection timed out
stack: ssh: connect to host stack port 22: Connection timed out
OpenJDK: ssh: connect to host openjdk port 22: Connection timed out
64-Bit: ssh: connect to host 64-bit port 22: Connection timed out
with: ssh: connect to host with port 22: Connection timed out
localhost: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-datanode-sUbuntu01.out
localhost: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
localhost: It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Starting secondary namenodes [OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
0.0.0.0]
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known
-c: Unknown cipher type 'cd'
It's: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it's: Name or service not known
'execstack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 'execstack: Name or service not known
'-z: ssh: Could not resolve hostname '-z: Name or service not known
0.0.0.0: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode-sUbuntu01.out
0.0.0.0: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
0.0.0.0: It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
noexecstack'.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname noexecstack'.: Name or service not known
<libfile>',: ssh: Could not resolve hostname <libfile>',: Name or service not known
link: ssh: Could not resolve hostname link: No address associated with hostname
it: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it: No address associated with hostname
to: ssh: connect to host to port 22: Connection timed out
or: ssh: connect to host or port 22: Connection timed out
you: ssh: connect to host you port 22: Connection timed out
guard.: ssh: connect to host guard. port 22: Connection timed out
VM: ssh: connect to host vm port 22: Connection timed out
stack: ssh: connect to host stack port 22: Connection timed out
library: ssh: connect to host library port 22: Connection timed out
Server: ssh: connect to host server port 22: Connection timed out
might: ssh: connect to host might port 22: Connection timed out
stack: ssh: connect to host stack port 22: Connection timed out
You: ssh: connect to host you port 22: Connection timed out
now.: ssh: connect to host now. port 22: Connection timed out
disabled: ssh: connect to host disabled port 22: Connection timed out
have: ssh: connect to host have port 22: Connection timed out
will: ssh: connect to host will port 22: Connection timed out
The: ssh: connect to host the port 22: Connection timed out
have: ssh: connect to host have port 22: Connection timed out
try: ssh: connect to host try port 22: Connection timed out
the: ssh: connect to host the port 22: Connection timed out
guard: ssh: connect to host guard port 22: Connection timed out
the: ssh: connect to host the port 22: Connection timed out
recommended: ssh: connect to host recommended port 22: Connection timed out
with: ssh: connect to host with port 22: Connection timed out
library: ssh: connect to host library port 22: Connection timed out
64-Bit: ssh: connect to host 64-bit port 22: Connection timed out
fix: ssh: connect to host fix port 22: Connection timed out
which: ssh: connect to host which port 22: Connection timed out
VM: ssh: connect to host vm port 22: Connection timed out
OpenJDK: ssh: connect to host openjdk port 22: Connection timed out
fix: ssh: connect to host fix port 22: Connection timed out
highly: ssh: connect to host highly port 22: Connection timed out
that: ssh: connect to host that port 22: Connection timed out
with: ssh: connect to host with port 22: Connection timed out
loaded: ssh: connect to host loaded port 22: Connection timed out
14/06/04 15:36:02 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Any advice?

Comment: why dont you create new user for hadoop, and connect that user with localhost using ***'ssh localhost'*** and then start hadoop with user... it may work try it..

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because hadoop binaries are built for 32 bit.  You get this warning on trying to run this on a 64 bit VM.  One option is to compile the sources for 64 bit.  Other  option is to update your hadoop-env.sh and add -XX:-PrintWarnings in HADOOP_OPTS.

I have discussed this in my [blog](http://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/hadoop-java-hotspottm-execstack-warning/)  here

Comment: I have since compiled from src with 64-bit java.